# Loop with overlay on hovered item via css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, overlay

I have to make some basic feature in one project. We have four elements, and when someone hovers on one of them, it should get yellow border (overlay). Overlay element should rotate in a circle and be always visible. 
It should look like this:

[image]

I've write a script in JS that rotate overlay element via css rotate, but I dont know how to loop it.. I mean when somebody hovers elements its working correctly, but when somebody hover last element (on the left) and next hover first element (on the top), then overlay element return back (move in different direction) - I know it's correct behavior, but I dont know how to loop this move that everytime overlay element will move in this same direction.

You can see basic markup I've made in codepen. It's not styled correctly, but I think most important here is JS right now.

[LINK](http://codepen.io/zyziu/pen/Exwqu)

JS:

```
// HOMEPAGE CIRCLE
var circle = $('#circle'),
    elems = $('.home-single-item'),
    overlay = $('#home-overlay'),
    arrow = $('.home-arrow'),
    texts = $('.home-single-item-text');

    texts.eq(0).addClass('active');

elems.on( 'mouseover', function( event ) {
    var index = $(this).index();      

    if ( index === 2 ) {
        index = 3;
    } else if ( index === 3 ) {
        index = 2;
    }

    var rotate = index * 90;
    var arrowz = ( index + 2 ) * 90;

    console.log( index );
    console.log( rotate );

    overlay.css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)'
    });

    arrow.css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + arrowz + 'deg)'
    });

    texts.removeClass('active');
    texts.eq(index).addClass('active');
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just thinking - would you not possibly make it easier to just add a hover effect class on each image instead of the jquery stuff?

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to have a rotation value that is always higher than the previous one.

This is just fairly messy psuedo code, but you could try something along the lines of:

```
var prevRotate;

elems.on( 'mouseover', function( event ) {

    // snip

    var rotate = index * 90;
    if(prevRotate && rotate < prevRotate){
        rotate = rotate + Math.ceil(prevRotate/360) * 360;
    }
    prevRotate = rotate;

    // snip

});
```

It might not work immediately, but ensuring that the new rotation is more than the previous rotation is what you want.